# Custom icons on google map not drawing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having problems with google maps, drawing icons was working fine few weeks ago in my project.  At some time the icons are very frequently drawing in partly and I don't know what is causing it.  It is both happening on my development machine and production server and on all machines.

I'm only using two different icons so I know the bitmap images are not corrupt.

Here below are two sample images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: a link would be more helpful than images

Comment: Have you specified z-index for icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get more help if you post your outputted JSON. Your gmaps JSON must not have quotes around width or height, like so: "picture":"/assets/dayhome.png","width":32,"height":37,"lat":53.5402,"lng":-113.628

Another fix is to include optimized:false which disables the html5 canvas (the squares that are cutting off the markers).

My much more detailed analysis here: [Canvas Tiles Cut Off Custom Markers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/3L1fW_n5E5c)

Answer (score 0):

Set `optimized:false` in your Marker options.

If `optimized` is `true` (the default), then your marker images are incorporated into the tiles. Unfortunately where markers cross tile  boundaries, they are not also used on the adjacent tile, so appear to be truncated at the edge of the tile. Using `optimized:false` forces the icons to be placed on the map as separate DOM objects.

Comment: Hello.  I tried that but it seems to have no effect:

=gmaps({"map_options" => { "auto_adjust" => false, "zoom" => 6,"center_latitude" => 65, "center_longitude" => -19},"markers" => { "data" => @json, :options => {:raw => '{ optimized: false }' } }})

Comment: In that case please supply a link. The API is run from the browser, and what ends up in the browser is important.